# Can't log into Magento 1.9 Admin Panel on work network

Tags: magento-1.9, admin-panel, admin-login

Never encountered this problem before until this morning all of a sudden. On the work network, we enter our admin Login details and nothing happens. The page refreshes and that’s all. No error message.

Tried different browsers, deleted cookies and cache, resetted. I just keep receiving the same errorless refresh?

However can access on our phones and on other networks?

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Please check in your log files.

Comment: have you tried deleting cookie adminhtml from your browser and try again?

Comment: Yeah, I've deleted all cookies and tried a number of times. I'm no Magento whizz by any means, I've checked system log and there's a number of parser errors?

Answer (score 1):

Clear your browser cookies and browser cache . That's will fix it.

Comment: Hi Ledian, I have already cleared cookies/cache and tried different browsers. Any other suggestions?

Comment: create new admin credentials with terminal ;)

Comment: Other admin's cannot log in either :/

Comment: @bjtb do you have access on terminal?

Comment: Do you mean to add new admin/users, yes I have access via my phone

Comment: yes, please try to add new user.

Comment: added a new user, still the same result. It seems like its a network problem. We can log in on any other network, apart from work's network. Any suggestions?

Comment: Change ip address of your computer using chrome extensions and try . Also check cookie domains for that site if they are set properly. Cookie domain you can find under core_config_data table.